# Flair on network profile is broken (for me at least), (sad panda fell off the slide)

Tags: bug, status-completed, combined-flair

I went to my [network profile flair page](https://stackexchange.com/users/440462/ryan?tab=flair) and ended up seeing this:

[image]

Which was unexpected so then [I tried to open the broke image in a new tab and ended up with the sad panda.](https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/flair/440462.png)

Can we fix the flair so we don't have any more sad pandas??

**Edit** to add more details:

I am on Linux Mint(13) and am using the Chrome Version: 23.0.1271.95

Comment: Hmm, your [glorious mountain flair](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/440462.png) looks fine to me.

Comment: @Bart when I click on your link I end up at the sad panda :-(

Comment: I get the error page as well @Bart.

Comment: Maybe it's just a lonely panda, asking you guys to keep him company? @Yannis

Comment: @Bart, hmmmm that could be it.

Comment: Works for me!  Have you tried http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ ?

Comment: Looks fine to me (Chrome current version)

Comment: @Andomar that only checks if the domain is up it won't check individual addresses. And obviously the domain is up or I couldn't be on meta talking about a sad panda!

Comment: @Joe "sad panda" is not an image, it's stackexchange.com's error page (which includes an image of a panda). Also, if it was caching, I probably wouldn't be seeing the error page as well. There are darker forces at play here than mere caching.

Comment: Hmm, good point.

Comment: @Bart as for the glorious mountains, they are the Windriver mountains in Wyoming USA. I went backpacking there last summer. Highly recommend them to anyone who enjoys the outdoors.

Comment: We store a local cache of each profile image on each of our servers. If the local cache gets corrupted (say a 0 byte image), people trying to view the flair on that server will get the error, but others might not. The caches are cleared weekly.

Comment: Ahah, so cache (but not the one I meant) was the answer! :)

Comment: @Oded so until the cache is cleared I can't access my flair?

Comment: It's just not flair @ryan...fair...I meant fair.

Comment: I went through all caches and manually cleared out invalid images. How's it now?

Comment: @Oded it's still giving me a sad panda, Bart is right it's totally not flair!

Comment: I've gone through and cleared another cache - how is it now?

Comment: @Oded it works now!

Comment: [You probably said no to his cheese](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6iHCFiSqIw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bad cached image caused this.

I have cleared the cache so it should work fine now.